# Neo4j detect node modification

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm using such kind of query in Neo4j database:

```
MERGE(n:type {key:"xyz"})
ON CREATE SET n.create_date = timestamp() 
ON MATCH SET n.update_date = timestamp()
SET n.att1=value1, n.att2=value2
```

The ON MATCH will help me to identify if a node has been found, but not if attributes have really been changed.

Is there any way we can use so we can detect that any attribute of a node has been changed ? For instance running the same query once again will change update_date attribute without really changing attributes. I would like to be able to detect that att1 or att2 has been changed.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible with APOC Triggers :

First, download and install APOC and enable it :

```
apoc.trigger.enabled=true
dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=apoc.trigger.*
dbms.security.procedures.whitelist=apoc.*
```

You can then add a trigger that will react when an `attr1` property is changed :

```
CALL apoc.trigger.add(
'updateTimestamp',
'UNWIND apoc.trigger.propertiesByKey({assignedNodeProperties},"attr1") as prop
WITH prop.old as oldProp, prop.new as newProp, prop.node AS n 
SET n.updated_at = timestamp()', {phase:'before'});
```

Test it :

```
CREATE (n:Node) SET n.attr1 = "hello"
MATCH (n:Node) RETURN n
╒════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"n"                                         │
╞════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│{"updated_at":1543313569105,"attr1":"hello"}│
└────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Update the node :

```
MATCH (n:Node) SET n.attr1 = "hellonew"
MATCH (n:Node) RETURN n
╒═══════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"n"                                            │
╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│{"updated_at":1543313626248,"attr1":"hellonew"}│
└───────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Do it again to check it is not triggered when the property is not changed :

```
MATCH (n:Node) SET n.attr1 = "hellonew"
MATCH (n:Node) RETURN n
╒═══════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"n"                                            │
╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│{"updated_at":1543313626248,"attr1":"hellonew"}│
└───────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: This is amazing ! I will mark this as solving my issue, just need one detail more, it it possible to add such trigger for all properties matching a specific name or should I add one for all properties I want to monitor ?

Comment: You can use UNWIND ["prop1","prop2"] AS prop CALL apoc.trigger..... and use `prop` alias in place of "attr1"

Comment: Since data is coming from an external system, I'm not sure 100% to have a fixed list of properties. I know however that the properties names will always start with "u_". I was trying to perform the SET only if property starts with u_ but no luck so far. Don't know if it's possible. Thanks a lot

Comment: For any node property, node creation and deletion have a look here: https://doc.linkurio.us/admin-manual/2.10.15/incremental-indexing/

Answer (score 1):

Based on the excellent support from Christophe, I played a bit with apoc and used this solution to create a trigger for all properties starting with u_

```
CALL apoc.meta.data() YIELD label, property, elementType WHERE elementType = "node" AND property =~ "^u_.*" WITH DISTINCT property AS key
CALL apoc.trigger.add(
'trig_upd_'+key,
'UNWIND apoc.trigger.propertiesByKey({assignedNodeProperties},"'+key+'") as prop
WITH prop.old as oldProp, prop.new as newProp, prop.node AS n
SET n.last_updated = timestamp()', {phase:'before'})
YIELD name
RETURN name;
```

I will continue to play with this, goal now is to find a way to create or remove the triggers in case of new or deleted properties.

BR
Rémi